# Why does my jar file contains nothing but the META-INF directory, when I deploy my artifact to Nexus by Maven?

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar, nexus

When I deploy my project to Nexus, I have managed to deploy a jar file, but this file contains nothing but a "META-INF" folder (which contains the pom.xml).

Where are the class files and other resources?
Is there any configuration tag in the pom.xml that specifies what files will be packed into the artifact? (By the way, I work with a parent pom.)

(I haven never tried to deploy artifacts to Nexus before, this is my first attempt.)

The code is under the test/java folder.

[image]

Comment: Where do you have located your class files? Show your pom file? How did you deployed? Command line ? via 'mvn clean deploy' ?

Comment: Hi, I used the "mvn clean deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=deploy.snapshots::default::http://nexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/deploy.snapshots" command to deploy

Comment: The code is under the "test" folder. Could it be the problem?

Comment: If you simply want to package those classes into a jar you need to have them in src/main/java. The area src/test/ will not be packaged into a jar file.

Comment: Thank you, it works under the main/java folder!
How can I mark your comment as a solution?

Comment: By the way, how can I package those classes into the jar under src/test folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to package those classes into a jar you need to have them in src/main/java. The area src/test/ will not be packaged into a jar file

If you like having a jar file which contains the things from src/test/ which is only in rare cases usefull you have to go a different way like the following:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

But you have to be aware using such dependency must be done like this:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>groupId</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <version>version</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

Here it is important to use 'test-jar'.
The src/test/ area is usually used for unit tests which usually don't need to be packaged into a jar file.

Comment: Thank you, it works like a dream!

BTW my files go under src/test folder, because I'm writing my selenium test utility library, and this uses Maven test dependencies which can't be accessed from under src/main.